# Z370 fancontrol Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, acpi, fancontrol, lm-sensors

My configuration is:

```
#sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
#System: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z370 HD3P [Default string]
#Board: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z370 HD3P-CF
#Kernel: 4.15.0-041500-generic x86_64
#Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (6/158/10)
```

Also, i have CPU 4pin cooler and 3pin 120mm cooler on board.

I have problem with 3pin cooler. It has to big RPM. Info from sensors:

```
it8686-isa-0a40
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.70 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in1:          +2.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in2:          +2.06 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in3:          +2.09 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in4:          +0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)  ALARM
in5:          +1.22 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in6:          +1.25 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
3VSB:         +3.41 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.12 V)
Vbat:         +3.19 V  
fan1:         415 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:         954 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +30.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +41.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +19.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp4:        +29.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp5:        +33.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high = -124.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp6:        +33.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
intrusion0:  ALARM



acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +16.8°C  (crit = +18.8°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp3:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +29.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +29.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +29.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +27.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +27.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +32.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +29.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

from sensors-detect

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8686
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
```

I tryed to config fancontrol,but it works only with 4pin CPU cooler. I don't like that fancontrol can't control 3pin cooler(or i do it wrong)

Also, my mother board has Smart Fan system, and i set good config for both coolers depends on CPU temperature. But when Ubuntu booting, something else controlling my coolers, not BIOS Smart Fan. When i reboot system, both coolers get low RPM, like my Smart Fan config.

I think that is some dependency with ACPI. If I boot Ubuntu with acpi=off, coolers are work at low RPM, but i lose HT and six virtual cores, if i loaded as acpi=ht, coolers has big RPM whatever.

Also i use it87 module, and force_id 0x8686, from [it87 module by groeck](https://github.com/groeck/it87), because after Ubuntu installation sensors didn't show RPM and pwmconfig didn't work.

I want that BIOS Smart Fan controls my coolers, not Ubuntu. Is here any solutions.

PS: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD: I updated bios version my mother board(HD3P) from f4 to f6c and bug gone.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. I found a strange behavior.

```
1. I set config in BIOS Smart Fan when 3 pin cooler has 300 RPM.
2. System is booting.
3.Sensors:
fan1: 363 RPM (min = 0 RPM) //4PIN
fan2:  960 RPM (min = 0 RPM)//3PIN
fan3: 0 RPM (min = 0 RPM)

4.I sent PC to suspend. 
5.I returned PC from suspend and login to Ubuntu.
6.Sensors:
fan1:         363 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)//4PIN
fan2:         269 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)//3 PIN
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
```

I think it's bug.

But, now it's solution, just sent and return to suspend.